# jquery push not works in $.get method

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

in this example:

```
function detailFormatter(index, row) {
        var html = [];
        $.each(row, function (key, value) {
        if(key == 'id')
        {
            html.push(key);
            $.get("function/conversation/message/"+value, function(data, status){
                html.push(data);
                alert(data);
            });


        }

        });
        return html.join('');
    }
```

first `html.push(key)` works.

alert works.

but second`html.push(data)` not works.

what is my wrong?

Comment: What does "not works" mean? Are there any errors in the console? If yes, can you post it? Can you provide the input data?

Comment: @secelite no error in console.  and html.push work before and after $.get. also I test something like this in $.get: html.push('test') ... it's not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem will be that $.get is asynchronous operation.
So if your result on return html.join(''); is not what you expected don't be surprised, because the operation might not be finished at that time.

Comment: how can solve it? it try `$.get("function/conversation/message", function(data, status){
                html.push(data);
                return html.join('');
            });`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Set the option `async` to `false`. Refer to the  [API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-settings).

Comment: There is multiple solution to this problem. 
1. Do it sync, rather than async.
2. Use promises
3. Save the value from async operation into storage/element and generate event when all operation are finished.

Comment: ;) np, but the problem with sync is that your browser will basically "hang" and wait for response from the server and won't respond at all. So be aware of that. And add at least some timeout for cases where the server is not responding. For more details look into jQuery documentation ;)